# How do you read a text file without losing odd characters?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, text, encoding

I would like to read a text file into an array of strings using System.IO.File.ReadAllLines. However, ReadAllLines strips out some odd characters in the file that I would like to keep, such as chr(187). I've tried some different encoding options, but that doesn't help and I don't see an option for "no encoding."

I can use FileOpen and LineInput to read the file without modification, but this is quite a bit slower. Using FileSystemObject also works properly, but I would rather not use that.

What is the best way to read a text file into an array of strings without modification in .net?

Comment: Could you post the code of how you do this now?

Comment: Remember that a `string` is a data type for a "series of characters". If you want to retain the exact way your file looks currently you should probably use an array of bytes. Otherwise you have to know the encoding to give the bytes a meaning that can be represented in a string.

Comment: Due to different encodings, please be specific and state exactly what character for CHR(187) you are expecting to see. For example, "RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK". Is that the one you are looking for?

Comment: Now I am using ss = File.ReadAllLines(infile, System.Text.Encoding.default). I realize I could use an array of bytes, but I would prefer to use strings since I process the strings. More importantly, when I read a file I would like to be sure I am getting ALL the file, without some characters stripped out.

Comment: When I say chr(187), I mean that the value of that byte in the file is 187. I realize that it has to get converted to some character in Windows, and I don't care which character that is. But I would like to be able to see that character in my string as a character equal to chr(187).

Comment: Then you actually want bytes, not characters.  See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such concept as "no encoding". You *must* find out the right encoding, otherwise you can't possibly interpret the data correctly.

When you say "chr(187)" what Unicode character do you mean?

Some encodings you might want to try:

- Encoding.Default - the system default encoding
- Encoding.GetEncoding(28591) - ISO-Latin-1
- Encoding.UTF8 - very common in modern files

Comment: When I say chr(187), I mean that the value of that byte in the file is 187. I realize that it has to get converted to some character in Windows, and I don't care which character that is. But I would like to be able to see that character in my string as a character equal to chr(187). Now, that character is missing when I use ReadAllLines and any of the three encoding options above.

Comment: I am guessing the code page you want is 1252 Western European (`Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`). Are you sure you are ‘missing’ characters completely? `ReadAllBytes(..., Encoding.GetEncoding(28591))` and also most locales' values of `Encoding.Default` will convert every byte to *some* character or the other (although in 28591's case it'll be a control character), so if they're not making it through you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: GetEncoding(1252) doesn't do it. Yes, the characters are stripped out of the file. If I do a ReadAllLines immediately followed by WriteAllLines, the output file is smaller than the input file.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to read the raw bytes.

Use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) to read them into an array (don't do this for large files), or use a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) to read chunks of bytes at a time.

Comment: I don't want to use raw bytes because I am processing string data. It is too slow and cumbersome to use bytes for this. I would like to be able to read a text file and be confident that I am getting the entire file with no characters missing.

Answer (score 0):

The characters that were stripped out were at the beginning of the file. It turns out they were the byte order marks for UTF-8. File.ReadAllLines and File.ReadAllText strips out the byte order marks, while LineInput and FileSystemObject functions do not.

If I had explained in the question that the odd characters were at the file beginning, I imagine I would have gotten a quick answer. I'll give Jon Skeet credit for the best answer to the question I posed.